# Highest Score Python

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to make this code work. I need to input a text file, that has a list of names and scores, then I need to split the name from the score, then use an if statement to check if the score is greater than the minimum score.

The text file looks like:

```
Jan  86 
Drew  92 
Blake  85 
Alex  81 
Taylor  88 
Jordan  72
Cam  89
```

I have the following code so far:

```py
SCORE_POSITION_IN_ENTRY = 0
NAME_POSITION_IN_ENTRY = ""


def main (student_name, student_score):
    print (f"Highest score: {student_score}")
    print (f"Achieved by: {student_name}")

def read_file (scores):   
    list_of_grades = ""   
    data_list = []
      
    infile = open('scores.txt','r')
    list_of_grades = infile.readline()
    
    while (list_of_grades != ""):
        data_list = int(list_of_grades)        
        list_of_grades = infile.readline()
    
    infile.close()
      
    return data_list


def find_max_score(data_list):
    entry_in_list = []
    maximum_score = 0
    
    #splitting the list
    entry_in_list = data_list.split('')
      
    current_score=int(entry_in_list[SCORE_POSITION_IN_ENTRY])
      
    if current_score > maximum_score:      
        maximum_score = current_score
        student_name = entry_in_list[NAME_POSITION_IN_ENTRY];
        student_score = entry_in_list[SCORE_POSITION_IN_ENTRY];
        
    return student_name, student_score


main()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.
"I'm having a hard time" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Your posted code does not run; it depends on a private file.  Unless you've isolated your problem to reading the file, it should not be part of your post.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your file input with a test case (e.g. list) that elicits the problem.

Comment: Yes, please post a sample of the text file.

Comment: Your posted code only calls the `main` function, which only prints two lines. It even calls the main function incorrectly, since it doesn't pass the two required arguments when calling. The `read_file` and `find_max_score` functions are not run at all, nor are they called anywhere. In other words, your code is a loose collections of functions that don't interact, and nothing will happen, except for a `TypeError`.

Comment: Okay, so *what is your question*? What happened when you tried to use the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? What parts of it do and don't seem to be doing what they're supposed to? Did you try to test that? What do you think is preventing you from making the code work?

Comment: The link you posted is not accessible. Does your text file look different from my answer?

Comment: The URL was not useful to us, since it requires authentication. I fixed the formatting of the example file contents. While we're at it, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: Sorry It's my first time using Stackoverflow, I'm a freshman in college taking a Python class for the first time.

Comment: Jan  86 
Drew  92 
Blake  85 
Alex  81 
Taylor  88 
Jordan  72
Cam  89
 this is what consists of the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textfile has two spaces between the names and the scores.  This code will work:

```
def main(filename):
    student_name, student_score = find_max_score(read_file(filename))
    print(f"Highest score: {student_score}")
    print(f"Achieved by: {student_name}")


def read_file(filename):
    data_list = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as reader:
        for line in reader.readlines():
            data_list.append(line)
    return (data_list)


def find_max_score(data_list):
    max_score = 0
    best_student = None
    for entry in data_list:
        name, score = entry.split('  ')
        if int(score) > max_score:
            max_score = int(score)
            best_student = name

    return (best_student, max_score)


main('scores.txt')

#output:
Highest score: 92
Achieved by: Drew
```

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom, you're a lifesaver. Have a blessed day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)) for reading the file an the `max()` function for getting the maximum score.

```py
import csv

with open("scores.txt") as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile), delimiter="\t")

names, scores = [r[0] for r in data], [r[1] for r in data]
scores_dict = dict(zip(scores, names))

max_score = max(list(scores_dict))
person = scores_dict.get(person)
```

In this case, `max_score` would be the maximum score, and `person` would be the person who achieved the maximum score.

Answer (score 0):

Making things a bit cleaner.

Note:

- Doesn't handle duplicates Example: Drew  93 and Taylor  93 have same score.(Can be done if it is required)

```
class ScoreIdentifier:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def get_scores_from_input(self, to_dict=False):
        score_list = list()
        score_dict = dict()
        with open(self.file_name, 'r') as input_file:
            for line in input_file.readlines():
                if to_dict:
                    key, value = line.split("  ")
                    score_dict.update({key: int(value)})
                else:
                    score_list.append(line)

        if to_dict:
            return score_dict
        return score_list

    def get_max_score_using_dict(self):
        # Get dictionary of items from file
        score_dict = self.get_scores_from_input(to_dict=True)
        # Using max method on index 1 finding max
        return max(score_dict.items(), key = lambda k : k[1])

    def get_max_score(self):
        score_list = self.get_scores_from_input()
        max_score = 0
        best_student = None
        if score_list:  # Empty score list check
            for idx, entry in enumerate(score_list):
                name, score = entry.split('  ')
                # If there are same blank space between first name, second name and score
                # then below piece of code isolates them Ex:Input "Ross  Taylor  93" output: (['Ross', 'Taylor'], 93)
                # *name, score = entry.split('  ')


                if int(score) > max_score:
                    max_score = int(score)
                    best_student = name

        return best_student, max_score


if __name__ == '__main__':
    score_obj = ScoreIdentifier('scores.txt')

    student_name, student_score = score_obj.get_max_score_using_dict()
    print(f"Highest score: {student_score}")
    print(f"Achieved by: {student_name}")

    student_name, student_score = score_obj.get_max_score()
    print(f"Highest score: {student_score}")
    print(f"Achieved by: {student_name}")
```